# Metric space problem (Triangle inequality)

Tags: inequality, metric-spaces

Let $X = \mathbb{R}^+$

$f\colon X\times X \to [0,\infty)$

(Triangle inequality)

$$\frac{|x-y|}{(1+x)(1+y)}\leq\frac{|x-z|}{(1+x)(1+z)}+\frac{|z-y|}{(1+z)(1+y)}$$

I only known than $|x-y|=|x-z+z-y|=|(x-z)+(z-y)|\leq|x-z|+|z-y| $

Comment: What has $f$ got to do with anything you wrote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to prove that
$$|x-z|(1+y)+|y-z|(1+x)\geq|x-y|(1+z)$$ or
$$\left(|x-z|(1+y)+|y-z|(1+x)\right)^2\geq(x-y)^2(1+z)^2$$ or
$$(x-z)^2(1+y)^2+2(1+x)(1+y)|(x-z)(y-z)|+(y-z)^2(1+x)^2\geq(x-y)^2(1+z)^2.$$
Now, $$(x-z)^2(1+y)^2+(y-z)^2(1+x)^2-(x-y)^2(1+z)^2=$$
$$=(x-z)^2(1+y)^2+((y-z)(1+x)-(x-y)(1+z))((y-z)(1+x)+(x-y)(1+z))=$$
$$=(x-z)^2(1+y)^2+(2y-x-z+xy+yz-2xz)(xy+x-z-yz)=$$
$$=(x-z)^2(1+y)^2+(2y-x-z+xy+yz-2xz)(1+y)(x-z)=$$
$$=(1+y)(x-z)((x-z)(1+y)+2y-x-z+xy+yz-2xz)=$$
$$=(1+y)(x-z)(x+xy-z-yz+2y-x-z+xy+yz-2xz)=$$
$$=(1+y)(x-z)(2xy-2xz-2z+2y)=2(1+x)(1+y)(x-z)(y-z).$$
Thus, we need to prove that:
$$(1+x)(1+y)|(x-z)(y-z)|+(1+x)(1+y)(x-z)(y-z)\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Comment: It isn't obvious

Comment: @Ozjasz Goldberg Is $|x|+x\geq0$ not obvious?

Comment: Where is |x|+x≥0?

Comment: @Ozjasz Goldberg $x$ it's $(1+x)(1+y)(x-z)(y-z).$ Do you want to see a proof that $|x|+x\geq0?$ I am ready to show.

Comment: I know why |x|+x≥0 but i don't know why (|x−z|(1+y)+|y−z|(1+x))^2≥(x−y)^2(1+z)^2 is (1+x)(1+y)|(x−z)(y−z)|+(1+x)(1+y)(x−z)(y−z) ≥0

Comment: It's a full expanding. I am ready to show. I used the formula $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$ and $x(y+z)=xy+xz$. I am ready to explain.

Comment: I also used formula but I have something else

Comment: OK. Wait please. I'll explain.

Comment: Thank you very much. I see it now

Comment: @Ozjasz Goldberg You are welcome!